# Angular named router outlet no matched routes

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am working on an application that uses lazy-loaded modules for each main part of the app. I have one that I two router outlets in a primary one and one called details.

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: BooksComponent, resolve: {books: BooksResolver}, 
    { path: ':id', component: BookDetailsComponent, resolve: { book: BookResolver},outlet: "details"},
];
```

with the HTML like below

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>     
<router-outlet namme="details"></router-outlet>
```

Then each book item I have a router link like below

```
 [routerLink]="['/', { outlets: { details: [book.id] } }]"
```

When I click on an item in I get the following error: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: '53'. Currently I have the details displaying in the primary router outlet but I can not get the details to show when a user clicks on the book item. I am not sure why this is not working I looked in the documentation and This seems to be the correct way of doing it haveing all routes at the same level. ANy help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably not the cause of your issue but you have a typo in `<router-outlet namme="details">`, should be "name".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with multiple exits, so LET me give you a little example that I hope makes sense to you

```js
    {
        path: 'a', component: AComponent, children: [
          {path: 'd', component: DComponent},
          {path: 'c', component: CComponent,outlet:'right'},
          // a/(d//right:c)
        ]
      },
```

In the component `AComponent`

```html
<a [routerLink]="['./',{outlets:{primary:['d'],right:['c']}}]">d/c</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
<router-outlet name="right"></router-outlet>
```

Multiple egress can be regarded as child routes

Comment: What do you mean by multiple exits?

Comment: It worked but why would I use'./ vs an empty string? When I click on one of the links it loads the resource but if i click on a new link it clears the router link and then I have to click it again to load the resource.

Comment: `./` Path of the current route